# Ethernet internet connection disconnects automaticially

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, internet

I am using Lubuntu 15.04 on my PC. I am having trouble with the internet connection it automatically disconnects while using. I am not seeing any network disconnected notification on my pc, still i can't even access the router's control page..
I had checked restarting the network manager service, when i do that the Ethernet is now not even detecting...

After a reboot everything works fine and i am having the problem again after a couple of minutes

Comment: Are you running a "non-router-device-made-Wi-Fi?" If yes then that's the problem.

Comment: I have a router with d-link wifi router with ethernet. 
I am using Ethernet to connect my pc to internet.
My internet connection automatically stops working on my pc, that's my problem.

Comment: Do you use Ethernet or wifi to connect to your router?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I am using Ethernet cable to connect to my router...

Comment: lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 command echoed nothing
I am pasting the full output of
'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Phe0bgUf